# Different Firebase user.uid on Frontend and Backend with Next.js and Firebase

Tags: firebase, next.js

I am building a web application using Firebase and Next.js for the first time and running into an issue.

Here is a piece of code that I'm using to create users both on SSR and CSR pages.

```js
export async function createAnonymousUser(): Promise<User | undefined> {
  const auth = getAuth();
  try {
    const userCredential = await signInAnonymously(auth);
    return userCredential.user;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error creating anonymous user: ", error);
  }
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that the user.uid provided by Firebase differs between the frontend and the backend. Consequently, I'm struggling to maintain user consistency across different pages and components.

Am I misunderstanding the usage of Firebase and Next.js in some way? I would appreciate any suggestions to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new anonymous user by calling `signInAnonymously`. Instead of calling this function on both front-end and server component, you should call it either on front-end and pass the auth token to api, or create user on server component and pass the `uid` as prop to front-end.

Comment: I only create users on the client side, and when I make a request to the API, I insert the Token into the header and do the authentication on the server side. thank you.